Uniform Convergence of integral with parameter
I need to prove that there is no uniform convergence of $I(\alpha) = \int_{0}^{1}{\sin(\frac{1}{x})\frac{1}{x^{\alpha}}dx}$ where $\alpha \in (0,2)$
what I've tried so far:

Let's prove pointwise convergence first. Fix $\alpha_o \in (0, 2)$ now let's do substitution and get: $(1) \int_{1}^{\infty}{\frac{\sin{t}}{t^{2-\alpha}}dt}$. Now using Dirichlet's Criteria we understand, that $(1)$ converges, hence we have pointwise convergence.

We need to use negation of Cauchy's convergence test to prove that there is not uniform convergenc, so we need $\exists \epsilon \forall B>0 \exists b_1, b_2 \exists \alpha : |\int_{b_1}^{b_2}{\frac{\sin{t}}{t^{2-\alpha}}dt}| \ge \epsilon$


I'm having big troubles to come up with such $b_1,b_2,\alpha$ and find $\epsilon$ using them. please, help me out!

Let $b_1 = \frac{\pi}{4} + 2n\pi$ and $b_2 = \frac{\pi}{2} + 2n\pi$ where $n$ is a positive integer. For any $B >0$, we have $B < b_1 <b_2$ for all sufficiently large $n$. We also have $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \leqslant \sin t \leqslant 1$ for all $t \in [b_1,b_2]$.
Hence, with $\alpha \in (0,2)$ it follows that
$$\left| \int_{b_1}^{b_2} \frac{\sin t}{t^{2-\alpha}} \, dt\right|=  \int_{\frac{\pi}{4} + 2n\pi}^{\frac{\pi}{2} + 2n\pi} \frac{\sin t}{t^{2-\alpha}} \, dt\geqslant \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\int_{\frac{\pi}{4} + 2n\pi}^{\frac{\pi}{2} + 2n\pi} \frac{dt}{t^{2-\alpha}}\geqslant \frac{\pi}{2\sqrt{2}}\frac{1}{(\frac{\pi}{2} + 2n\pi)^{2-\alpha}} $$
Taking $\alpha = 2 - 1/n \in (0,2)$ we get
$$\left| \int_{b_1}^{b_2} \frac{\sin t}{t^{2-\alpha}} \, dt\right|\geqslant \frac{\pi}{2\sqrt{2}}\frac{1}{(\frac{\pi}{2} + 2n\pi)^{1/n}} $$
Since $(\frac{\pi}{2} + 2n\pi)^{1/n} \to 1$ as $n \to \infty$ we can choose $n$ to be sufficiently large such that we also have
$$(\frac{\pi}{2} + 2n\pi)^{1/n} \leqslant 2,$$
and, thus, for all $B>0$ there exist $b_1, b_2$ with $b_2 > b_1 >B$ and an $\alpha \in (0,2)$ such that
$$\left| \int_{b_1}^{b_2} \frac{\sin t}{t^{2-\alpha}} \, dt\right|\geqslant\frac{\pi}{4\sqrt{2}}$$
Whence, the improper integral does not converge uniformly.

thanks a lot! could you me some intuition about choosing such sequences to deal with Cauchy negation? why did you choose exactly $\frac{\pi}{4}, \frac{\pi}{2}$?

@JaneDoe:  It need not be exactly those two numbers. We just need to find an infinite sequence of intervals $[b_1^{(n)},b_2^{(n)}]$ where the sine function takes positive values.  That makes it easy to estimate the integral over that interval since the integrand does not change sign.
